# Trouble with sorting list and "for" statement snytax

Tags: python, list, sorting

I need help sorting a list from a text file. I'm reading a .txt and then adding some data, then sorting it by population change %, then lastly, writing that to a new text file.

The only thing that's giving me trouble now is the sort function. I think the for statement syntax is what's giving me issues -- I'm unsure where in the code I would add the sort statement and how I would apply it to the output of the for loop statement.

The population change data I am trying to sort by is the [1] item in the list.

```
#Read file into script
NCFile = open("C:\filelocation\NC2010.txt")

#Save a write file
PopulationChange =
open("C:\filelocation\Sorted_Population_Change_Output.txt", "w")

#Read everything into lines, except for first(header) row
lines = NCFile.readlines()[1:]

#Pull relevant data and create population change variable
for aLine in lines:
    dataRow = aLine.split(",")
    countyName = dataRow[1]

    population2000 = float(dataRow[6])
    population2010 = float(dataRow[8])

    popChange = ((population2010-population2000)/population2000)*100
    outputRow = countyName + ", %.2f" %popChange + "%\n"
    PopulationChange.write(outputRow)


NCFile.close()
PopulationChange.close()
```

Comment: If you need to sort the data, you cannot write it as you go, you need to load it all in memory so you can sort it.

Comment: Can you elaborate? I'm fairly new to Python.

Comment: You can write line by line, or you can write the entire file. But you can't (easily) write lines in random locations

Comment: I've fixed the indentation, if it is incorrect please back out the changes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to read all of the lines in the file before you can sort it.  I've created a list called `change` to hold the tuple pair of the population change and the country name.  This list is sorted and then saved.

```
with open("NC2010.txt") as NCFile:
    lines = NCFile.readlines()[1:]
    change = []
    for line in lines:
        row = line.split(",")
        country_name = row[1]
        population_2000 = float(row[6])
        population_2010 = float(row[8])
        pop_change = ((population_2010 / population_2000) - 1) * 100
        change.append((pop_change, country_name))

    change.sort()
    output_rows = []
    [output_rows.append("{0}, {1:.2f}\n".format(pair[1], pair[0]))
                        for pair in change]
    with open("Sorted_Population_Change_Output.txt", "w") as PopulationChange:
        PopulationChange.writelines(output_rows)
```

I used a list comprehension to generate the output rows which swaps the pair back in the desired order, i.e. country name first.

Comment: Thanks for the assist! This helped out a lot.

Answer (score 1):

You can fix your issue with a couple of minor changes. Split the line as you read it in and loop over the sorted lines:

```
lines = [aLine.split(',') for aLine in NCFile][1:]

#Pull relevant data and create population change variable
for dataRow in sorted(lines, key=lambda row: row[1]):
    population2000 = float(dataRow[6])
    population2010 = float(dataRow[8])
    ...
```

However, if this is a csv you might want to look into the [`csv`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html) module. In particular `DictReader` will read in the data as a list of dictionaries based on the header row. I'm making up the field names below but you should get the idea. You'll notice I sort the data based on `'countryName'` as it is read in:

```
from csv import DictReader, DictWriter

with open("C:\filelocation\NC2010.txt") as NCFile:
    reader = DictReader(NCFile)
    data = sorted(reader, key=lambda row: row['countyName'])

for row in data:
    population2000 = float(row['population2000'])
    population2010 = float(row['population2010'])
    popChange = ((population2010-population2000)/population2000)*100
    row['popChange'] = "{0:.2f}".format(popChange)

with open("C:\filelocation\Sorted_Population_Change_Output.txt", "w") as PopulationChange:
    writer = csv.DictWriter(PopulationChange, fieldnames=['countryName', 'popChange'])
    writer.writeheader()
    writer.writerows(data)
```

This will give you a 2 column csv of `['countryName', 'popChange']`. You would need to correct this with the correct fieldnames.

Comment: The csv module is definitely the right way to parse a csv. CSV might look like a simple format, but getting it right is surprisingly tricky. +1

Comment: Great! This is really helpful.